# how to Implement function just like get_next_frame using ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

**I'm trying to implement a function which can get the next frame,
but when i call this function at the 3rd time**

```
int ret = decoder.get_next_frame(mat);
ret = decoder.get_next_frame(mat);
ret = decoder.get_next_frame(mat); // error
```

**ffmpeg avcodec_send_packet return err, and the msg is 
  [h264 @ 0x8bd2780] Invalid NAL unit size (10848 > 766).
  [h264 @ 0x8bd2780] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
the var with prefix '_' are all member var**

```
int VideoDecoder::get_next_frame(cv::Mat& mat) {
int ret = 0;
bool got_frame = false;

while (!got_frame && av_read_frame(_p_fmt_ctx, _p_packet) >= 0) {
    if (_p_packet->stream_index == _video_stream_index) {

        ret = avcodec_send_packet(_p_dec_ctx, _p_packet);

        if (ret < 0 || ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        }   

        while (ret >= 0) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(_p_dec_ctx, _p_frame);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            }   

            sws_scale(_p_img_convert_ctx, _p_frame->data, _p_frame->linesize,
                    0, _p_dec_ctx->height, _p_frame_rgb->data, _p_frame_rgb->linesize);
            mat = cv::Mat(_p_frame->height, _p_frame->width, CV_8UC3, _p_frame_rgb->data[0]);
            got_frame = true;
        }   
    }   
    av_packet_unref(_p_packet);
}   

if (got_frame) {
    return _p_dec_ctx->frame_number;
}   

return 0;
}
```

**so what's the problem?**

Comment: Hello to stack overflow (SO). 
We here at SO are eager to help you, but please play along our rules, to make it easier for us. 
Consider reading through the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and 
taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Especially consider reading through 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you try with another video just to be sure the problem isn't with the file being decoded?

Comment: the video file is ok, because if i change the code from "while (!got_frame && av_read_frame(_p_fmt_ctx, _p_packet) >= 0)" to "while ( av_read_frame(_p_fmt_ctx, _p_packet) >= 0)" all the frame can be cv::imwrite correctly

Comment: Please do not spam unrelated languages. You yourself know that you're writing C++ here.

Comment: useless code removed

Answer (score 0):

I re-check the code, finally found a memory err, the video data released unexpected in other place, so the above codes seems ok